# Calculo del determinante de una matriz nXn

Tags: java, matrices, matriz, fórmulas-de-matriz

Estoy intentando programar la inversa de una matriz y para ello necesito calcular entre otras cosas el determinante. Pero tengo un problema al generar las submatrices/cofactores. Me aparece un error de fuera de rango. Lo he revisado varias veces y no entiendo porque ocurre.

Lo que tengo entendido es que debo de sacar el determinante de cada submatrix para obtener el determinante completo de la matriz origen. Además el error que me da siempre es en la linea de `submatrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j];` dentro de la función getSubMatrix().

Aquí os dejo el código:

```
public double determinantMatrix(double [][] matrix) throws IllegalAccessException {

    if(matrix.length != matrix[0].length){
        throw new IllegalAccessException("Invalid dimensions");
    }

    if(matrix.length == 2){
        return matrix[0][0] * matrix[1][1] - matrix[0][1] * matrix[1][0];
    }

    double det = 0.0;
    double[][] deter = new double[matrix.length][matrix.length];
    for(int i = 0; i <matrix[0].length; ++i){
        det += Math.pow(-1, i) * matrix[0][i] * determinantMatrix(getSubMatrix(matrix,matrix.length, matrix.length));
    }
    Log.e("Determinante ",String.valueOf(det));
    return det;
    }

double[][] reduceMatrix(double[][] matrix, int row, int column){
    double[][] m = new double[matrix.length-1][matrix.length-1];
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix.length; ++j){
            if(i != row && j != column){
                m[a][b]= matrix[i][j];
                ++j;
            }
        }
        if(i != row){
            ++i;
        }
    }
    return m;
}


public double[][] getSubMatrix(double[][] matrix, int row,int column){
    double [][] submatrix = new double[matrix.length - 1][matrix.length - 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; i != row && j < matrix[i].length; ++j){
            if(j != column){
                Log.e("Submatrix["+String.valueOf(submatrix.length)+"]["+String.valueOf(submatrix.length)+"] i",String.valueOf(i)+ " row: "+ String.valueOf(row) + " j:" + String.valueOf(j) + " column: "+ String.valueOf(column));
                if( i >= row){
                    i -= 1;
                }
                if(j > column){
                    j -= 1;
                }
                Log.e("i",String.valueOf(i)+ " j:"+String.valueOf(j));
                Log.e("submatrix ",String.valueOf(submatrix.length) + " matrix "+ String.valueOf(matrix.length));
                submatrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
                Log.e("SubmatrixNext["+String.valueOf(submatrix.length)+"]["+String.valueOf(submatrix.length)+"] i",String.valueOf(i)+ " row: "+ String.valueOf(row) + " j:" + String.valueOf(j) + " column: "+ String.valueOf(column));
            }
        }
    }
    return submatrix;
}
```

¿Que tendría que cambiar o corregir?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.Length` devuelve el número total de elementos en el arreglo. Así lo dice la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.length?view=net-6.0).

Entonces si tienes una matriz de 2x2, `Length` será 4. Pero como planteaste el código, creerá que se trata de una matriz de 4x4 y por eso se sale del rango.

En un caso como este necesitas saber cuántos elementos tiene cada dimensión del arreglo. Lo puedes lograr con [`Array.GetLength`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getlength?view=net-6.0#system-array-getlength(system-int32))